# Ratio word problem total cost of magazine and number of customers who bought the magazine

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[image]

During January of this year, Utopia Magazine sales reached a total of £ 488800. The ratio of normal price customer to discounted price customer was 5:2. How many customers in total bought this magazine?

I have tired to work this out by multiplying the total with each ratio and dividing by 7 but i dont seem to get the answer correct, can any one help with this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $n$ be the number of normal price customers and $d$ be the number of discounted price customers. Then you have that
$$2n=5d$$
and
$$2.8n+2.1d=488,800$$
since $2.1=2.8-0.25\cdot 2.8$. Can you solve this system of equations for $n$ and $d$, and then calculate the total number of customers $n+d$?

Comment: why does 2n=5d? That doesnt make sense to me. the number of discount customers is not equal to the number of Normal price customers

Comment: The ratio of $n$ to $d$ is $5:2$, so there are $5/2$ times as many $n$ as there are $d$, and $n=(5/2)d$, or $2n=5d$.

Comment: oh i see, thank you!

Comment: @italy No problem! If this is helpful, don't forget to $\checkmark$ and $\uparrow$! :D